# MySQL support not available. after upgrade to 16.04.1 from 14.04

Tags: php, mysql

When I visit the webpage, all I see on the screen is "MySQL support not available." I have checked to see if `mysql` was running, and it is, `apache` is running, and I can see my phpinfo.php test file.

I'm confused as to what I need to check to get my site back running. It is a php site with a `mysql` database. I can access the databases with `phpmyadmin`, but i'm now lost as to what else to check.

I already changed the `virtualhost` file to change the `eth0` to `ens33` (or whatever it was called) since I guess networking names have changed. I have been reading around this site for 2 days now, and haven't found whats wrong.

I know php is now `7.0` instead of `5.5`. My site may very well may not even work on php 7, but I would think I would see something other than just that message. Any help in the right direction would be great. The site that wont work is an older version of invisionpower board. Anything that uses mysql I get that message.

Comment: A little more specifics would go a long way. For example, what CMS are you using? Wordpress?

Comment: edited the first post

Comment: I think I figured it out. All my php code has deprecated and/or removed functionality in php 7, such as mysql_connect, etc.I think I will have to remove php 7 and go back to 5